# ruby -> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_deprecate_constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hi I'm getting following error when I do bundle install

> Symbol not found: _rb_deprecate_constant

any ideas

```
❯ bundle install
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_deprecate_constant
  Referenced from: ~/.gem/ruby/2.6.5/gems/etc-1.2.0/lib/etc.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_deprecate_constant
  Referenced from: ~/.gem/ruby/2.6.5/gems/etc-1.2.0/lib/etc.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

[1]    98241 abort      bundle install
```

Comment: This seems to be quite new. Started to have it today in the morning with ruby 2.7.2 as well. Yesterday it was working fine. I got to run what I needed by using ruby 3.0.0